# Unexpected no such file error in zsh function

Tags: zsh

I have defined this function in `zsh`, but it cannot work on my computer.

```
function m() {
    local path=/Users/james/Music/cloud_music_link
    local cmd="ls $path | sed -n $1p"
    echo `$cmd`
    # afplay `$cmd`
}
```

It always said:

> m:3: no such file or directory: ls /Users/james/Music/cloud_music_link | sed -n 10p

and when I copy the `ls /Users/james/Music/cloud_music_link | sed -n 10p` and run it in `zsh`, everything is ok, why would this happen?

And the folder `cloud_music_link` is a soft link, I am not sure if this matters.

Comment: If your question is about zsh, don't tag bash

Comment: ...and btw, the general answer is "don't put commands in variables". See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the file (or subdirectory) at a given position inside of your given directory first to `echo`, and then to `aplay`? Easily done, in a way compatible with both bash and zsh:

```
m() {
    local num=${1:-1}
    local dir=/Users/james/Music/cloud_music_link
    local -a files=( "$dir"/* )
    local file=${files[$(( num - 1 ))]}
    echo "$file"
    afplay "$file" &
}
```

See:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I finally figure it out, you can see my code above, I think it's the problem of the name `path`, I changed it to `p` and it magically worked... I want to use this function to listen to music, I just need to input `m [num]` and it will play a song, and I don't know which number corresponding to which song lol.

Comment: Heh. You're right -- the name `path` is indeed special in zsh (one of the many places where it violates the POSIX standard -- according to POSIX, only all-caps names should be special to the shell).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out, it is because the name of the variable `path`, I changed it to `p` and everything works OK. The name `path` will conflict with `zsh`.

This code works:

```
function m() {
    local p=/Users/james/Music/cloud_music_link/
    song="$(ls $p | sed -n $1p)"
    echo $song
    killall afplay 
    afplay "$p$song"&
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work correctly with songs having all possible filenames -- `touch $'a song\nabout whales.mp3'` will create a file which this would treat as two names, so it would either try to play `a song` or `about whales.mp3`. It's also dependent on `ls` to not quote any nonprintable characters in your names -- if a name contains, say, a `õ` and your version of `ls` represents it as `\334` (most implementations will be smart enough to do this only for truly nonprintable characters -- this is only an example), then `afplay` would be looking for a filename that contains `\334` in it.

Comment: (of course, if your `ls` tries to escape that newline by replacing it with a `?`, `aplay` might be instead looking for `a song?about whales.mp3`, but that won't work either in a context where globs aren't honored -- and if globs *were* honored, you'd have a whole new host of problems).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hey, thanks for your advice. About the first situation, I tried, it did exist. I think it is lucky that I don't have any song with its name contains `\n`. And for the second point, I find a song called `Позови меня тихо по имени`, and this code works magically fine on my macOS, I am using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: `\n` is a two-character string starting with a backslash and `$'\n'` is a one-character newline literal -- not quite the same thing. But, yeah, sounds like your `ls` is fine for the names you've tested with so far -- I just don't advise the practice, because somewhere there will exist a name where they're *not* okay. And why use code that has known bugs (even if they only happen with really unlikely names) when you coud use code that doesn't?

Comment: To provide another example, `[hello world].mp3` can be replaced with `e.mp3` or `o.mp3` by the shell if you have something by the latter name that exists in the current directory and it's expanded unquoted (because that's a glob expression). zsh doesn't do that in as many cases as POSIX-compliant shells do, but it's still a case where you're adding potential corner cases without cause (would definitely happen on the `echo` command line if you used this function in bash, for example).